# GitFlow - Master or Develop branch which to mirror

Tags: git-flow

I'm new to GitFlow. Should `develop` branch be a mirror of `master` branch all the time or the other way around ?

As a background of situation, after doing so many releases (e.g. merge pull request from `release` branches), there are extra commits on `master` branch that `develop` branch don't have. I tempted to delete 'develop' branch and create fresh 'develop' branch.

Answer (score 1):

In Git Flow, most of the time `develop` should be ahead of `master`, but perhaps in *state* only. In other words, `develop` should contain all commits on `master` except perhaps the merge commits caused by completing a `release` branch, which is exactly what you're witnessing. After you do the first `hotfix` branch, all of those commits will be brought into `develop` at the same time.

You could just ignore those merge commits, but personally I prefer having `develop` be fully up to date with `master`. Fortunately there is a simple solution to this, which is, after merging `release` into `master`, skip the merge of `release` into `develop`, and instead merge `master` into `develop`. In this way the new merge commit on `master` is also brought into `develop`. Having `develop` be fully ahead of `master` in both *state* and *commits* is useful for knowing you won't accidentally blow away a hotfix in production when you deploy because someone forgot to merge it all the way down to `develop` or `release`.